# How to clear ip associated to client device

Tags: wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, wireless-access-point

I am using Raspberry Pi in AP mode. I have restricted users to only one. First I connected to laptop. Then after after closing laptop, I tried from mobile. Mobile is not getting ip address, looking like is associated to laptop mac, It will get cleared after some time(exactly dont know). Will any one help me to clear that association so that I can connect to other devices. Purpose is only one user at a time to AP.

Comment: I restricted using /etc/udhcpd.conf with start 1.2.3.10 end 1.2.3.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed "opt lease" to 15, which is 15 sec in udhcpd.conf file.